# Integral $\int_0^1x^{\frac{1}{x}}{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration

I've been trying to work out $\int_{0}^{1}x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}} {\rm d}x$ and by using integration by inversion, I've managed to get it down to $1-\int_{0}^{1} x^{\frac{1}{x}} {\rm d}x$, and I was wondering if there's any way to solve this, either as an infinite series or in closed form? Possibly in terms of the $\Gamma$ function? I'm very stuck

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: @rafa11111 This is not the same integral

Comment: you could  write  it as $\int_0^1 e^{\frac 1x \ln(x)}\,dx$ and use the series expansion for $e^x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Comment: @Winther it isn't indeed, I thought OP could use it as The Integrator suggested.

Comment: @TheIntegrator the integral of $(\frac{\log(x)}{x})^n$ does not converge on $[0,1]$.

Comment: The power tower does not converge for $x<e^{-e}$

Comment: The integral $1 - \int_0^1 {\sqrt[x]{x}} \,dx$ is actually equivalent to $\int_0^\infty {\frac{W(x)}{xe^x}} \,dx$ where W(x) is the Lambert W function and is $\approx 0.6465032$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661808/evaluate-the-definite-integral-int-0-infty-fracwxxex-dx/4790376#4790376.

Answer (score 0):

I think I now have worked out why I was having such issues. As pointed out by @user121049 the power tower stated in my question is only defined from $e^{-e}$ to $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, and so the integral is undefined between 0 and 1. As such, below is my solution for the integral of the same curve, but over the portion on which it is defined:

$\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}} {\rm d}x = e^{\frac{1}{e}+1}-e^{-e-1}-\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{a}\frac{c^b(e^{-c}+(-1)^{a+b}e^c}{c!(a-c)!\prod_{d=1}^{b+1}(a+d)} \approx 1.24$

Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: By expressing the power tower in terms of a product log function I get the same answer by numerical integration. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+W(y)+exp(-y)%2Fy+dy+for+y%3D-1%2Fe+to+e

Comment: How did you find this answer?